# Make StartDate as Previous EndDate in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use a query daily, where I specify a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
dt_Start >= '11/1/2013' and dt_start < '11/2/2013'
```

I want to declare `@startDate` and `@Enddate` variables such that the next time when I run the query, `@StartDate` will be `'11/2/2013'` and `@EndDate` will be current date (which is easy, `convert (varchar(10), getdate(), 101)`)

But can someone please help me with finding the `@StartDate`?

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL? MS SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SQL Sevrer. and I dont want to use this Startdate daily. because I dont run this query when I  am on leave or on sat, sunday and holidays.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: He's not storing them as strings... converting it to varchar(10) is just removing the time component

Comment: Yes - because, I have huge amount of data and if I keep datetime datatype, then result runs out of limit. that's why I have to conver in varchar(10).